# Can MeshMixer export models for color 3D printing?

Tags: 123d-catch, obj

I have captured several models using [123D Catch](http://www.123dapp.com/catch) and [Autodesk ReCap 360](https://recap360.autodesk.com/).

I do all my "clean up" work in [MeshMixer](http://www.123dapp.com/meshmixer) to prepare the models for printing, and while exporting to STL works great for printing on my home FDM printer I haven't been able to get color files exported.

I would like to export scanned models from MeshMixer and upload them to an online printing service (i.e. [Shapeways](https://www.shapeways.com/) or [iMaterialise](https://i.materialise.com/)) and have them printed on high end color machines.

My current workflow goes as follows.

1. Export raw model (OBJ) from 123D Catch or ReCap.
2. Open model in MeshMixer v10.10.170.
3. Remove unnecessary parts of the model.
4. Export model as OBJ, OBJ with per vertex color, or VRML.
5. Zip model and exported texture files and upload to an online service.

The file in MeshMixer looks great, but ends up with either jumbled or nonexistent  textures when it's uploaded to an online service. I'm guessing I'm exporting the file wrong for 3D printing, or possibly that I need to do some post-export editing to make everything line up correctly.

Answer (score 4):

Color is only displayed if you set MeshMixer to render VertexColor:

```
MM menue/View/MeshColorMode/VertexColor
```

Color should be visible if VertexColor is active.

- Meshmixer is a sculpting program, so it isn’t made for taking exact
  measurements, creating mechanical parts, or creating architecture
  models.
- Basic rendering options make pretty screenshots, but advanced users
  might want to add in backgrounds or set up custom lighting.

Also, you can read more about this matter on **[this link.](http://www.sculpteo.com/en/tutorial/prepare-your-model-3d-printing-meshmixer/3d-file-analyse-and-export-meshmixer/#analyze-file)**